# Django openid application deployment in google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, openid

I am trying to deploy my django application in google app engine. The basic application works fine through django-nonrel app.

My another application contains openid(google mail) login. All the pre-requests i have installed my machine and configuration updated based on django-nonrel app. Application deployed successfully but while redirecting to openid login its show the below error:

**OpenID Failed**

OpenID discovery error: Error Fetching XRDS document: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'readline'

I was try to find out this not getting related posts, this issue is based on the third party app so where i get OpenID app for google app engine or need to do in different way. If anybody knows please guide me on this. Thanks.